# TransformListener Could not find a common time /base_link and /map

Tags: ros, clock, tf2, rostime, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded bags on different computers/robots during an experiment and now I'm trying to replay them. All computers were synchronized with chrony. Now, I play all bags with the same rosbag command.

However, when I call `listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), transformStamped);` from another node, I get the error `Could not find a common time /base_link and /map`.

Everything is fine when I look with RVIZ, same with roswtf. I ran tf view_frames and everything seems normal to me.

I also tried `rosparam set /use_sim_time "True"` and then rosbag play --clock, but it does not seem to make any difference.

One of my colleagues recommend that I always call waitForTransform before lookupTransform. Is this required, or should lookupTransform work on its own?

[frames2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13245592716403643.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12428/transformlistener-could-not-find-a-common-time-/base_link-and-/map/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding a call to canTransform or waitForTransform before lookupTransform solves the problem. For example, `listener.waitForTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0),ros::Duration(1));` the line before lookupTransform makes everything work.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-22**:
You will likely want to use waitForTransform documented in the tf tutorials http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials or if you are performance limited the tf::MessageFilter will allow you to do it without blocking execution http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1MessageFilter.html